# Do murderous zombies take all your loot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When you are killed by a zombie in Minecraft, do they take *all* of your stuff or just your armor and weapons? I ask because a zombie killed me and now I am trying to find my stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the wiki (and confirmed by personal experience) certain zombies have the ability to pick up and wear a set of armor and wield a single item in their hand. See [Armed Zombie](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie#Armed_Zombie)

Therefore, if you are looking for your stuff, a set of your armor (what you were wearing or carrying) may be on the zombie still, and an item may be in its hand, but the rest of your stuff should be on the ground unless it has despawned, which I believe happens after 5 minutes of being in a loaded chunk.

Comment: @anthony Of course, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

Some zombies can take them, some can't. If you find the zombie with your stuff, who wont be far off, and then kill him, you can get your stuff he picked up back. But if he hasn't and its been more than five minutes, they probably despawned.